# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'...works for the instructor

Tags: string, object, attributes

I've looked at other post about this same issue and can't find the answer. My code is exactly like the class online (both below, but I did shorten up the directories). Why is it working for the instructor and not me?

---

Below is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

data = open("lifeexpectanciesusa.txt", "r").readlines()

dates = [ ]

malelife = [ ]
femalelife = [ ]

for line in data:
    date, malelife, femalelife = line.split(",")
    dates.append(date)
    malelife.append(malelife)
    femalelife.append(femalelife)

pyplot.plot(dates, malelife,"bo-", label="Men")
pyplot.plot(dates, femalelife, "mo-", label="Female")

pyplot.legend(loc="upper left")
pyplot.xlabel("Year")
pyplot.ylabel("Age")
pyplot.title("Life Expectancies for men and woman in the USA over time")

pyplot.show()
```

---

Below is what the instructor has:
[Instructor code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LayyR.png)

---

The error message I get is :

```
pyplot.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-56-0283726
068cb>", line 12, in <module>
malelife.append(malelife)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two variables of the same name in the same scope. Either `malelife` is a list, or it's a string; it can't be both `"John"` and `[]` at the same time. You want to append the `malelife` string into the `malelife` list; but in fact, there's just one `malelife`, and at that time it's a string. Rename one of them (similarly for `femalelife`) and the problem will go away.

Note that the instructor had distinct variable names; the two versions are *not* the same as you claim. Your "shortening" is the problem. If one version works and the other doesn't, you should look to what you changed to find what the problem was.

Comment: Hey Amadan, I just saw that...after spending almost an hr. looking at the code! I was looking at trying to delete the post so i didn't look too stupid!

Comment: No worries, everyone has a brain fart now and then, and I especially include myself...

Comment: But the interesting thing...is that the professors plotting has a exponential distribution where as mine is very linear.

Comment: That is a different question, please ask it as such (after trying to figure it for yourself).